# Logging of all interprocess interactions of the target Android application

Tags: android, ipc, trace, android-binder

I want to collect all requests to Binder, which makes an arbitrary Android application  running on a real device with root permissions. To be more accurate, I want to write a program that could log all the interprocess interactions of an arbitrary target application.

How can i do it without [jtrace](http://newandroidbook.com/tools/jtrace.html)? Are there any open source utilities or frameworks for this task?

Comment: If you can install a custom kernel, this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392864/2384186.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I can't install custom kernel and also i can't install drivers. It has to be an application. Like jtrace.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399539/3290339) might be helpful.